# Expected number of steps from state x to y

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

> Find Expected number of steps from state 3 to 1 of a makorv chain with the following transitiion matrix
> $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
> 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
> 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\  
> 0.5 & 0.25 & 0.25 \\  
> \end{array}\right)$$

Since in states 2 and 3, there is only a 0.5 probability to go to state 1.
The probability to go from 3 to 1 = $0.5 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^3 + ... = 1$

And the expected number is 1/1 = 1 which doesn't make sense.

I am not sure what is wrong with my computation and how to find the expected number of steps to go from 3 to 1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you start in state 3, on first step you may go next to any of the states 1,2,3 with the given probabilities. And same if you are temporarily in state 2. So there are many ways to get from 3 to 1 in several steps, e.g. by going (3,3,2,3,2,1) which is but one of the ways to get to 1 in 6 steps.

Comment: so is it like solving $ 1 * 0.5 + 2* 0.5^2 +  3* 0.5^3 + ... $

Comment: Yes it is like that but the individual probabilities are more complicated than simply powers of 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Markov property.
I'm just going to pretend that $2$ and $3$ are the same states, bcause clearly the evolution doesn't depend on which one you're in.
Conditioning on what happens in the first step, we obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E_2(\tau_1)
&
=
\mathbb E_2(\tau_1 \mid X_1 = 1) \mathbb P_2(X_1 = 1)
+
\mathbb E_2(\tau_1 \mid X_1 = 2) \mathbb P_2(X_1 = 1)
\\&
=
\tfrac12 1
+
\tfrac12 \mathbb E_2(\tau_1 + 1)
=
\tfrac12 \mathbb E_2(\tau_1) + 1.
\end{align*}
Importantly, there is this "$+1$" term. This corresponds to the fact that the first step needs to be counted.
Rearranging this, we obtain
$$
\tfrac12 \mathbb E_2(\tau_1)
=
1,
\quad\text{or, equivalently,}\quad
\mathbb E_2(\tau_1)
=
2.
$$
I've spelled out all the details carefully here because this is a really fundamental idea in Markov chains. "Take one step and see what happens." That's what my Markov chain supervisor always used to say to me!

You can use your idea directly.
You correctly calculated
$$
\mathbb P_2(\tau_1 = k) = (1/2)^k,
\quad\text{or, equivalently,}\quad
\mathbb P_2(\tau_1 \ge k) = (1/2)^{k-1}.
$$
Now, you just need to take expectations:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E_2(\tau_1)
&
=
\sum_{k \ge 1}
\mathbb P_2(\tau_1 \ge k)
=
\sum_{k \ge 1}
(1/2)^{k-1}
\\&
=
\sum_{k \ge 0}
k \mathbb P_2(\tau_1 = k)
=
\sum_{k \ge 0}
k (1/2)^k
\\&
=
2.
\end{align*}